# python parallel Popen

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, subprocess

I've been puzzling this for whole night now...

```
makeflags = ['--prefix=/usr','--libdir=/usr/lib']
rootdir='/tmp/project'
ps = set()

def configModule(m):
    print m
    return Popen(["./autogen.sh"] + makeflags, cwd=rootdir+"/"+m)

for module in ['mod1','mod2','mod3' ... 'mod10']:
    ps.add(configModule(module))

os.wait()
```

I was expecting it will start 10 processes and executing ./autogen.sh in parallel. However, what I observed was the first few configModule seemed to exit as soon as the functions were called. I only see the "print m" statement, but not the actual output of ./autogen.sh within "mod1". However, after about mod4, the code started to run in parallel. I can see the CPU utilization is high as well as the output has been generated in different module folders.

Any idea why the first few modules did not produce ./autogen.sh result?

P.S. If I run this code in serial (i.e. using subprocess.call instead of Popen) it works correctly.

Comment: I also tried to use multiprocessing module, unfortunately, I can overcome the unpickle problem as I tried to start a pool of processes in a class...

Comment: I assume it is a copy/paste error, but shouldn't `m` be passed to the `Popen` call instead of `module`?

Comment: @jro yeah, good eyes! I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me, and should start all the processes. You're not giving us much to work with: what behavior differs?

You're not redirecting output in the code you pasted, so you're probably seeing the childs' `stderr` streams. One thing though is that:

```
os.wait()
```

…will only wait for 1 process. You might want to use the return value from `Popen`, and call `wait` or `communicate` on each of the child processes. You can then additionally use the return values to ensure they're all dying successfully:

```
# Instead of os.wait():
for p in ps:
    p.wait()
    print 'A process returned:', p.returncode
```

Hopefully, they should all be 0 if everything is returning OK.

Comment: `communicate()` is useless here if none of the 3 streams is redirected to a `PIPE`. `wait()` should be enough here...

Comment: Ah, I think I might know what happened now... because this is a non-blocking call, I saw "print m" before the task is completed. The ./autogen.sh maybe queued up and still working on it. I will wait a little longer and see if all folders are fine.

Comment: @glglgl: `communicate` becomes equivalent to a `wait` in this case. Edited nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

A similiarly built up program with da dummy system call works as expected:

```
from subprocess import *

makeflags = ['--prefix=/usr','--libdir=/usr/lib']
rootdir='/tmp/project'
ps = dict()

def configModule(m):
    print m
    p = Popen("echo start %s; sleep %d; echo finish %s" % (m, 10-m, m), shell=True)
    #p.m = m
    return p

for module in range(10):
    ps[configModule(module)] = module

while ps:
    done = set()
    for p in ps:
        s = p.poll()
        if s is not None:
            print "Module %d: %d" % (ps[p], s)
            done.add(p)
    for p in done:
        del ps[p]
#os.wait()
```

Are you sure that the output is really missing, or is it just delayed?

BTW:

```
for module in ('mod%d' % i for i in range(1, 11)):
```

is more elegant...